# C# BinaryReader.ReadChar throws "System.ArgumentException: The output char buffer is too small" when reading NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networkstream, binaryreader

When reading C# `NetworkStream` (from stream-type TCP socket), `BinaryReader.ReadChar` occasionally throws exceptions `System.ArgumentException: The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)'`

All buffers have their default sizes (none of them are manually set) and setting bigger buffer sizes does not affect the issue.

And what is completely discouraging:

- The exception does not occur when using breakpoint and walking step-by-step through the line with `ReadChar` call
- The exception does not occur if `ReadChar` is preceded by `Thread.Sleep(1000)` (but can still occur with smaller timeouts)
- The exception does not occur when using `BinaryReader` on `FileStream`, where all precise bytes of TCP-server's answer are stored.

So, what can be the time-related issue with buffering single characters from stream a socket?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue too. And here are some facts about it:

1. `System.ArgumentException: The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)'` is known to be related to UTF-8 encoding problem (invalid character code) rather than to buffering problem - [Detials here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/187884/BinaryReader-overflow-error)
2. `NetworkStream` (`Read` and other methods) is known to return only the amount of bytes which is already present in system network buffers instead of blocking until all requested data will be recieved - [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731129/under-what-conditions-does-a-networkstream-not-read-in-all-the-data-at-once). So, one needs to use `Read` in a loop to get all requested data
3. `BinaryReader` is known to throw an exception when getting less data from `NetworkStream` than it expected, instead of using a loop to retrieve the rest (and YES, I am sure, this means a bug!) - [Details here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c739b4d1-7223-43e2-b989-cd685d9d0134/question-about-binaryreader)

So, my solution was to partially reimplement `BinaryReader` (I have called my class `BinReader`) adding some useful features and making proper Read method with a loop:

```
public int Read( byte[] buf, int off, int count ) {
    int read = 0;
    while( read < count ) {
        int toread = count - read;
        int portion = BaseStream.Read( buf, off, toread );
        read += portion;
        off += portion;
    }
    return read;
}
```

That has solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to fix this, but changing `reader.ReadChar()` to `Convert.ToChar(reader.ReadByte())` seemed to work for me.