# Socket.SendFile send big file error 87

Tags: c#, winsock, winsock2, system.net.sockets

I use the standard method of sending a file.

```
internal bool SendToServer(string filename)
    {

        if (null == _netSocket || !_netSocket.Connected) CreateSocketConnect();

        try
        {

            _netSocket.SendFile(filename);

            File.Delete(filename);

            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            CloseSocketConnect();
            string error = string.Format("exception: {0} error code: {1} stacktrace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.ErrorCode, ex.StackTrace);
            _twriter.AddMessage(string.Format("-> {0}", error));
            Logger.Instance.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But there is one problem. If the file is large, more than 1.5 GB, then I get an error
WSA_INVALID_PARAMETER - 87

How can I fix this and can I even do it or look for another option for sending the file?

Comment: I'd suggest you to look for alternate option to send such files. Though strange why it throws `WSA_INVALID_PARAMETER` error. in this case, API says - 'One or more parameters are invalid.' What are you passing in filename, when you receive such errors?

Comment: Something like this zip_2098_23062017000737.zip.base64.response

Comment: Is this a file name? If not, please share the relevant code.

Comment: Yes it real filename.

Comment: I updated code in question

Comment: Post the complete error message or exception's stack trace as well.

Comment: Exception: The parameter is set incorrectly error code: 87 stacktrace: in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendFile (String fileName, Byte [] preBuffer, Byte [] postBuffer, TransmitFileOptions flags)
    In System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendFile (String fileName)
    In ARInvoker.Receiver.SendToServer (String filename) in c: \. Net \ ARClient \ ARInvoker \ Receiver.cs: line 94

Answer (score 0):

As per [Windows Socket Error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx),

> WSA_INVALID_PARAMETER
>   87
>   One or more parameters are invalid.
>   An application used a Windows Sockets function which >directly maps to a Windows function. The Windows >function is indicating a problem with one or more >parameters. Note that this error is returned by the >operating system, so the error number may change in >future releases of Windows.

We can only guess the possible invalid parameter. We should be you using Full file path. Also make sure to [receive the file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713664/why-does-my-client-socket-not-receive-what-my-server-socket-sends).  To get to the root cause of the error,You have to capture a [network trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing) .First enable the tracing by adding a [config entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) and reproduce the issue,you should get a detailed trace file.We can [read it to understand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/interpreting-network-tracing) root cause

**Edit:**

There is not much details in the network trace,so I looked at the source code of [Socket.SendFile](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,d9512eac446008f4) implementation . It looks like the call is simply going to
WinSock [TransmitFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565(v=vs.85).aspx) and this TransmitFile is throwing the **invalid parameter error** .So this is a winsock error ,here's the winsock PInvoke happening

```
// This can throw ObjectDisposedException.
                if (fileHandle != null ?
                    !UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.TransmitFile_Blocking(m_Handle.DangerousGetHandle(), fileHandle, 0, 0, SafeNativeOverlapped.Zero, asyncResult.TransmitFileBuffers, flags) :
                    !UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.TransmitFile_Blocking2(m_Handle.DangerousGetHandle(), IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, SafeNativeOverlapped.Zero, asyncResult.TransmitFileBuffers, flags))
                {
                    errorCode = (SocketError) Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                }
```

Comment: Information: 0 : [6928] Socket#25702951 - Создано подключение с 10.200.3.77:12994 к 10.200.2.235:7118.
Verbose: 0 : [6928] Exiting Socket#25702951::Connect() 
Verbose: 0 : [6928] Socket#25702951::SendFile()
Error: 0 : [6928] Socket#25702951::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - 87
Error: 0 : [6928] Exception in Socket#25702951::SendFile - Параметр задан неверно.
Verbose: 0 : [6928] Socket#25702951::Shutdown(SocketShutdown#2)

Comment: As you might have noticed, this error only occurs if the file is larger than 1.5 GB

Comment: As soon as we connect,it's disconnect.I was expecting to see hex data information.Timestamp also is immediate . Not showing any details:     Information: 0: [6928] Socket # 25702951 - Created connection from 10.200.3.77:12994 to 10.200.2.235:7118. Verbose: 0: [6928] Exiting Socket # 25702951 :: Connect () Verbose: 0: [6928] Socket # 25702951 :: SendFile () Error: 0:.

Comment: Error seems to be coming from winsock,added winsock tag to the question.

Comment: How I can to do this? Add winsock tag to the question.